# Library Folder Permissions

Tags: permissions, folder

We have a site named 'DistrictAccess' with a document library under it. In that document library we have many folders. I need to be able to stop inheritance on the 'Document' and devise a script to set/reset permissions on each folder.

Seems like everything I've tried will not allow me to break inheritance on the folders so I can assign custom permissions.

So this is what I have:

```
DistrictAccess
     Documents
          Folder1
          Folder2
          etc....
```

Can anyone set me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying in SharePoint online or on premise? Have you written code to break inheritance in event receivers or some thing else

Comment: Have you tried breaking inheritance on the list itself?

Comment: And what is your preferred method? Workflow? Javascript? Event Receiver?